# Draw a graph of f(θ)= sin(θ+2)

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I'm not able to understand the following graph. Because of `θ + 2` the graph is starting at 2 units left of 0. But how do I get those points? For eg. if I put `θ =-2`, it'll be `sin(0)=0`. But how do I get point of `1` and `-1` on `Y-axis`? I thought only `sin(π/2) =1` and `sin(3π/2) =-1`. But I'm not sure how do I put `π/2` in this equation? I'm also aware of the concept of `phase shift`.

[image]

Comment: It's $\sin(0)=0$.

Comment: It's actually $\sin(\pi/2+k2\pi)=1$ and $\sin(3\pi/2+k2\pi)=-1$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z$ (not only $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $\theta + 2 = \frac{\pi}{2} \implies \theta = \frac{\pi}{2} - 2$.  You can do the same thing for $\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Comment: But how would I put the π/2−2 on the x-axis? I just see the numbers on x-axis.

Comment: There's no way to be that precise on the given graph (no need, either) -- just eyeball it so the graph is shifted over by 2.

Comment: I'm taking Math course on my own, so pardon me. If I'm not wrong I should draw a graph of input of θ and output of sin(θ+2). But why in the example there is no π/2,π... and just regular numbers like 1,2... on x-axis. why?

Comment: You're right about the input and output.  The question's intent is to test your knowledge of phase shift, so once you know the general shape of the graph, you don't need to be too precise in drawing it.

Comment: So, I assume that as long as I draw right shape and assume π/2,π... or  1,2... on x-axis final answer is valid?

Comment: Yup!  You can always get a quick ballpark with $\pi/2 \approx 3.14/2 \approx 1.5$...